# Making 2 windows appear simultaneously in Red language

Tags: window, rebol, red

How can I make these 2 separate windows appear simultaneously and remain open thereafter unless the quit button is pressed?

```
   Red []

   view/flags [ below
            text "second view"
            f2: field "f2 text"
            ] 'no-buttons

   view/flags [ below
        text "first view"
        b1: button "Print f2 text" [print f2/text]
        quitb: button "quit" [quit]
    ] 'no-buttons
```

I tried to put second view in a function and call it from first view- but it shows only second view (first view is shown after second is closed by Alt-F4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to `view` is a blocking call that will run its own event loop, until it is closed. `view/no-wait` will open the window without a new event loop, so it will not block (still requires an event loop to process events). So you can open the first window as non-blocking, and the last one in blocking mode, for running the event loop:

```
view/no-wait/flags [
    below
    text "second view"
    f2: field "f2 text"
] 'no-buttons

view/flags [
    below
    text "first view"
    b1: button "Print f2 text" [print f2/text]
    quitb: button "quit" [quit]
] 'no-buttons
```